# Calculating time of a job in HPC

Tags: jobs, hpc

I'm start to use Cloud resources

In my project I need to run a job, then I need to calculate the time between the begin of the execution of the job in the queue and the end of the job

To I put the job in the queue, I used the command:

**qsub myjob**

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

the simplest (although not most accurate) way is to get the report of your queue system. If you use PBS (which is my first guess from your qsub command), you can insert in your script the options:

#PBS -m abe

#PBS -M your email

This sends you a notification at start (b) end (e) and abort(a). The end notification should have a resources_used.walltime with the information of the wall time spent.
If you use another queue system, there must be some similar option in the manual.